# How to set region color on Google geomap?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geomap

is it possible to set color for geomap?

Also I would like to listen community opinion about alternatives in Geo Coding solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Color of what?  Are you making custom polygons with GPolygon or what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the color for the regions used in the geomap.  This API page explains everything:

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html

Answer (score 1):

With version3 of geomap (as of 8Jan2014) - color fade from red to blue.

You can test the following code [here](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#geo_map%3a):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Country', 'Borat Sightings'],
     ['United States', 3],
     ['United Kingdom', 4],
     ['Kazakhstan', 7]
  ]);
  var options = {
        colors: [0xff0000, 0x0000ff]
      };

  var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  geomap.draw(data, options);
}
```

Also, [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/) is an alternative to googlemaps / geomap.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your options object pass in the hex for the colors you want. For instance 
 options['colors']=[0XEBEBEB,0XA3D5F8];
will give you those two colors as base.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the colors of country, world map, even background. Also
check:

```
 private void functionMap() {

                    "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html,width=device-width,user-scalable=yes; charset=windows-1252\">\n" +
                    "    <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://www.google.com/jsapi\"></script>\n" +
                    "    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
                    "     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});\n" +
                    "     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "      function drawRegionsMap() {\n" +
                    "        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([\n" +
                    "          ['Country', ''],\n"




                    "        ]);\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "        var options = {};\n" +
                    "\t\toptions = { \n" +
                    "                    datalessRegionColor: '#29ABE2',\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\t    backgroundColor: '#F3F3F3',\n" +
                    "\t\t\t\t\tcolorAxis: {colors: ['#0071BC']},\n" +
                    "                    keepAspectRatio: false,                    \n" +
                    "                    legend: false,\n" +
                    "                    tooltip: { textStyle: { color: '#0099CB', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: '10'} }\n" +
                    "                };\n" +
                    "\t\t\n" +
                    "        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));\n" +
                    "        chart.draw(data, options);\n" +
                    "    };\n" +
                    "    </script>\n" +
                    "  </head>\n" +
                    "  <body>\n" +
                    "  <div id=\"chart_div\" style=\"width: 100%; height: 100%;\"><div style=\"position: relative;\"><div dir=\"ltr\" style=\"position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;\"><div style=\"position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;\"></div></div></div></div>\n" +
                    "  \n" +
                    "</body></html>";

}
```